# how to retain a private ip of a vm before deleting and use it for another azure vm

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

how to retain a private IP of a VM before deleting and use it for another VM
I have provisioned a VM in azure with private IP and want to delete that VM which I provisioned and create a new VM with the same private IP using terraform I have come to know that we can do using the address module but couldn't find any solution can someone help?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-reserved-public-ip

required using terraform in azure

found this but couldn't go further,
address module to be implemented for terraform so that the environment IP is static so that we can retain IP even if we destroy the infrastructure .

Comment: you define private ip, so I dont see a problem there. what doesnt work for you

Comment: I am willing to use the same private IP which I deleted while provisioning a new VM

Comment: so where is the issue? if you deleted the vm - do that

Comment: what the thing is I have a VM with some private IP and some name if I delete that Virtual machine IP should be retained and when I provision a new virtual machine with the same name it should get the same private IP

Comment: retrieve its ip first and use that to create a new one? i dont see any issues here

Comment: how to retrieve and create a new VM using terraform and if I know how to do I wouldn't be asked in this

Comment: The possible means I think is to retain the NICs and assign them to the new VMs.